# Tkinter continuously loop main event

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I'm making a trivia game where data is from [www.opentdb.com](http://www.opentdb.com). I want it to continually loop through the main program after it tells you whether your answer is correct or not. (clicking an answer and shows green label but will stay at that screen). I would like it to wait a few seconds and have tried using .after(3000, main()) but do not know how to reset the screen and repeat.Im sorry if this sounds very confusing. Thank you for your assistance :)

```
from tkinter import *
import trivia
import html

t = trivia.Trivia()
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1366x768")
root.configure(bg='#4dc4ff')
root.iconbitmap("icon.ico")
root.title("Trivia Party!")
frame = Frame(root, bg='#4dc4ff')

class Buttons:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = html.unescape(text) # remove html entities
        self.correct_label = Label(root, text="Correct!", font=("Arial", 30), background="#98FB98", width=20, height=2) # green correct label

    def reveal_answer(self):
        if self.text == t.return_correct_answer(): # if its the right answer
            self.correct_label.pack(pady=175)
            frame.destroy()

        else:
            self.correct_label.config(text="Incorrect", background="#ff6347")
            self.correct_label.pack(pady=175)
            Label(root, background="#4dc4ff", text=("The correct answer was: " + t.return_correct_answer()),
                  font=("Arial", 40)).pack()
            frame.destroy()

    def create(self):
        Button(frame, text=self.text, borderwidth=0, highlightbackground="#00abff", font=("Helvetica", 30),
               command=self.reveal_answer).pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES)
        frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)



buttons = []
question = Label(frame, text=html.unescape(t.return_question()), font=("Arial", 25), height=3, bg="#00abff").pack(fill=X)
for i in t.all_answers: # t.all_answers is pulling all of the multiple choice answers ie "coke", "pepsi" "sprite"
    buttons.append(Buttons(i).create()) # i is the individual answer eg "pepsi" and is making a button
root.mainloop()
```

[image: basically stays at this screen]

Comment: Nowhere in the code do you call `after`.

Comment: you need to put the .after(ms, *func) in your function and call it somewhere once. If you just do .after(ms, *func) in your mainloop, the function just calls once.